# Sort multi array by number javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this multi array with a url and number in each inner array, how do i sort so the array is organized by highest number to smallest.

```
var arr = [
["http://example.com", "3"],
["http://example.com2", "1"],
["http://example.com3", "22"]
]
```

i want it to look like this

```
var arr = [
["http://example.com3", "22"],
["http://example.com", "3"],
["http://example.com2", "1"],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function with custom `compareFunction`, like this

```js
var arr = [
  ["http://example.com", "3"],
  ["http://example.com2", "1"],
  ["http://example.com3", "22"]
];

var res = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
});

console.log(res);
```